# DVD Upscaling on OS X

Tags: macos, dvd, zoom

"Full Screen" mode in OS X doesn't look as good as my PS3's DVD upscaler.  Is there a good way to play DVDs in OS X with high-quality upscaling zoom?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that VLC can do that, but I can't find a good howto to send to you.